# Problems reading data from Binary store

Tags: flutter, gradle

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> 2
> Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\shubham\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle10983516403080185149.bin offset 0 exists? true

Comment: Add more detail to your question.

Comment: i have the same issue , did you found the solution